# A Problem about Hypothesis Testing and Decision Making

Tags: statistics

I have a problem about the hypothesis testing and decision making as follows:

> A botanist wishes to test the null hypothesis that the average diameter of the flowers of a particular plant is 9.6cm. He decides to take a random sample of size $n$=80 and accept the null hypothesis if the mean of the sample falls between 9.3cm and 9.9cm; if the mean of this sample falls outside this interval, he will reject the null hypothesis. What decision will he make and will it be in error if
>   (a) he gets a sample mean of 10.2cm and $\mu$=9.6cm; 
>   (b) he gets a sample mean of 10.2cm and $\mu$=9.8cm; 
>   (c) he gets a sample mean of 9.2cm and $\mu$=9.6cm; 
>   (d) he gets a sample mean of 9.2cm and $\mu$=9.8cm.

Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this problem? I just do not so understand what the problem asks for and how to approach it. 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a vocabulary test. No calculation necessary!

(a) He will **reject** the null hypothesis, since $10.2$ is outside the range he has set. Since $\mu$ is in fact $9.6$, he will be **mistaken**.

(b) He will reject the null hypothesis, for the same reason as above. Since $\mu\ne 9.6$, he will be right.

You can do the others.